# C# Mandrill-dotnet SendMessageTemplate Serialization Error to Post

Tags: c#, mandrill

Im using [Mandrill-dotnet](https://github.com/shawnmclean/Mandrill-dotnet/blob/master/src/Mandrill/Messages.cs) 2.4.1.0 to send transactional emails from my C# application.
Every so often I get an Error saying: Serialization Error to Post: messages/send-template.json.

When checking Mandrill the email I have tried to send has been sent, so it might be a a problem with the data in the response.
I can sometimes see that there is a backlog at the time of the error, but I cant say for sure that is the problem.
I have a hard time finding out what the source of this error is and would appreciate any help in finding a way to resolve this as it seems hard to get to the actual error inside the Mandrill-dotnet code.

Best Regards
Tobias

Answer (score 1):

I see that in Mandrill-dotnet version 2.4.1, the JsonException was just swallowed and turned into a MandrillException (which we can check in the [sourcecode on github](https://github.com/shawnmclean/Mandrill-dotnet/blob/57690eec4653fa3fc5f1df1b050366b9235dd2b4/src/Mandrill/MandrillApi.cs#L118))

However, I think you have already made [a pull request and fixed this for version 2.4.181](https://github.com/shawnmclean/Mandrill-dotnet/blob/c8633970b54d16aacac3942902c3fa6cbc0a7206/src/Mandrill/MandrillApi.cs#L155).

From what I can tell so far, it seems that the source of the error is transient: similar content will be posted through to the Mandrill API absolutely fine without issue before and after the errors occur, but a clump will fail serialization.

Did you uncover anything further useful with the additional improved exception handling you added to Mandrill-dotnet?

Comment: I got a lot of these errors all of a sudden today after not changing anything in a while (eg. I didn't change my template). Wondering if you had the same today - that might suggest an issue their end today. Incidentally I was on a version below 2.4.181 but just upgraded now.